# How to benchmark internal implementation of one java method?

Tags: java, performance

I have been using `jmh` for few months, and it is a great framework, that gives out the measurement of different java methods.

Now what I would like to know is within that same method, that I have benchmarked with `jmh`, I would like for `x ns/op`, to know how much of this `x` was spent in native calls, and how much was spent in scheduling, etc...

I am not sure if there is a tool to do that.

Comment: You probably want to use a profiler. I have never used one, but you can simply try googling `java profiler` and I'm sure you'll find something that suits your needs.

Comment: Is `Valgrind` a profiling tool as well ? As I heard that it is used for finding memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe following link is some what closer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html you can find help info with command java -agentlib:hprof=help . But still it wont give you the time spent in scheduling, switching etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for is a profiler to give you the performance. I know on tool offhand that would be able to accommodate your request, however I am certain there is a number of Java profilers out there that could work for you just as well.

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/